# Changing CGDisplayMode properties

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

is it possible to change CGDisplayMode properties for a specific mode? the apple docs say Display Mode Standard Properties dictionary has been depreciated and i am looking for a way to change the height and width of a specific display mode.

Currently my program is capable of switching between the 9 prebuilt display modes for my screen but i can not figure out how to customize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn't make sense. A display mode **is** the properties. If it had different properties, it would be a different mode.

What you seem to be asking is if you can switch the display to a mode that the system does not provide. No, you can't. The system is providing the list of modes supported by the hardware.

It would probably be possible to write an IOKit driver, perhaps a kext, to claim that more modes were supported by the hardware and then try to drive the hardware in those other modes, but that would be very involved and possibly dangerous. (It's actually possible to damage hardware by trying to drive it in an unsupported mode.)

Comment: Makes sense and great answer, thank you. a slight branch from the main question, so for something like a full screen game application that allows you to set it to different display hight/width options, is it just allowing you to change it within the app and the height and width limitations for what is actually displayed is still regulated regulated by the current mode and the game is just using more available pixels??

Comment: You say your program is capable of switching among 9 supported display modes. That's what games typically do. They only let the user pick from among the supported modes. It is also possible (in fact [recommended by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_fullscreen/opengl_cgl.html)) to leave the mode alone, make a full-screen window, render to a lower-resolution GL FBO, surface or texture, and then blit it to the window at which point it will be scaled up.